# TEAMCITY REST API list of last 10 days of all buildTypes

Tags: rest, teamcity, birt

I'm using TeamCity 8.x, and I know how to get the last 10 days worth of builds for one buildType

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?buildType=<buildTypeID>&sinceDate=<10 days ago>
```

However, is there a way to get the last 10 days worth of builds for ALL buildtypes on a TeamCity server within one REST call?

I'm using BIRT and would rather not have to manually add a bunch of sources nor have a dynamically scripted source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try just dropping the build type locator?  For example:

`/app/rest/builds/?sinceDate=20140501T170952%2B1000`

Note that there will be other caveats to work around, such as in a build configuration that uses feature branches, TeamCity will by default only return builds from the 'default' branch.  Plus it will limit the response to 100 items.

[Loads of info here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildLocator)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that, in my experience if you use a date filter you will only ever get back 100 items even if you ask for more. I'm not sure if this a bug or by design but I've gotten around it by making multiple calls asking for a day at a time, which works fine for my use case.

Comment: I was able to get more than 100 items by adding &count=<arbitrarily high number> to the end of my REST call

Comment: Interesting, I will have to try it again, what version of TeamCity are your running?

Comment: I'm running TeamCity 8.1.3. Also "&count=-1" seems to pull everything for me too.

Comment: Well I'm stuck running 8.1 for a few more weeks but maybe it's something that's been changed recently, so I'll try again. Thanks.